# R - How to order a column in a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm working with some NBA data with R, and currently there's about 25 columns of various data in my data set. One of the columns is called "Efficiency" with type integer, and I'd like to order it to get the top 10 values in descending order. I'd also like to get the name, salary, and team (which are also columns in the data frame) corresponding to the top 10 "efficiency" values. How should I go about doing this? I'm just learning R, and just figured out how to mutate/add columns to existing frames, so I'm feeling a bit lost. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be helpful if you can provide a reproducible example as RonakShah commented, but it sounds like you should check out [`dplyr::top_n()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html).

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% top_n(10, mpg)

#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> 5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> 6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> 7  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> 8  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> 9  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> 10 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```